# What's the type of props that's been passed in setup function Vue3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to use a render function inside a setup function. I need to know what is the type of `props` inside `setup`'s scope.

```
import { h, PropType } from 'vue'
export default {
    props: {
        brand: {
            type: Object as PropType<String>
        }
    },
    setup(props) {
        /* Need to know the props argument type */
        const count = ref()
        return () => h('div', props.msg + count.value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`props` type is inferred automatically inside the setup scope, but you should create the component using `defineComponent` :

```js
import { h, defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        brand: {
            type: String //just use String
        }
    },
    setup(props) {
        /* you can get access to `props.brand` here with right type */
        const count = ref()
        return () => h('div', props.brand + count.value)
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using a `.ts` file and not a `.vue`. I think that disables the inference

Comment: No, I realized that you're missing to create your component using `defineComponent` function